# How to Use GuiDropFiles with GUI controls?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

How can I use `GuiDropFiles` with GUI controls?

I have several `edit` fields in my form, and I want to be able to drop files onto them separately and work with them.

This is what I came up with:

First, my controls are set up like this:

```
WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES=0x10

Gui, add, edit,  vedit1, %file_1%
WinSet,ExStyle, +WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, edit1
```

And my drag-drop routine is as such:

```
GuiDropFiles:  ; Support drag & drop.
    Loop, parse, A_GuiControlEvent, `n
    {
        thisfile := a_loopfield  ; Get the first file only (in case there's more than one).
        thiscontrol := a_guicontrol
        break
    }

    alert(thisfile . "`r" . thiscontrol)

    if(thiscontrol = edit1)
        guicontrol,,%edit1%, %thisfile%
    if(thiscontrol = edit2)
        guicontrol,,%edit2%, %thisfile%
    if(thiscontrol = edit3)
        guicontrol,,%edit3%, %thisfile%

return
```

I am using the [basic example](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#GuiDropFiles) from the autohotkey documentation.  I also tried the [example from here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/84961-drop-fileand-read-itover-gui-editbox-depending-on/), but it keep saying, "not dropped on an edit box".
Any clue would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (after a few lost hours).

First, I didn't need this:  `WinSet,ExStyle, +WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, edit1`

and I didn't need to set any styles on the edit controls.

All I needed was this, which works since my edit controls have the variable-name starting with "UI_file":

```
GuiDropFiles:  ; Support drag & drop.

    Loop, parse, A_GuiEvent, `n
    {
        thisfile := A_LoopField  ; Get the first file only (in case there's more than one).
        thiscontrol := a_guicontrol
        break
    }
    ;alert(thisfile . "`r" . thiscontrol)

    If InStr(A_GuiControl, "UI_file")
        guicontrol,,%A_GuiControl%, %thisfile%

return
```